# increment cell column by +1 with each iteration

Tags: excel, vba, increment, copy-paste

im trying to figure the title out. But im new to vba and cant think of a simple enough way to copy from cell C29 in one workbook and paste in cell KJ54 in another workbook. i want KJ54 to increase with 1 with each iteration, so next time it will be KK54 and next time KL54 etc. ( basically, every time i run this macro it will paste C29 to the cell in the next column).

tried messing around with something like:

```
Dim i As Range
Set i = Range("KJ")
i = i + 1
```

expected KJ to be KK in next iteration when running macro again

im just too much of a newbie to find something that works.

I know a workaround for this in excel itself but it requires a bit more manual work, i like to be as lazy as possible :)

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: `Set i = i.Offset(0, 1)` - but consider to chose a better name for your range variable...

Comment: Usually people use Dim i As Long with i being the iteration of the loop and Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("KJ54") for the range (names can vary but it's easier to understand this way). Then you use something like For i = 1 To endOfYourLoopVariable with rng.Offset(,i-1) (this way you start with your KJ and the next iteration, you go to the next column.

Comment: Typically this would be done by finding the next available column of row 54, mimicking a user selecting the rightmost cell in row 54, then CTRL-Left to find the last used cell and then right one for the empty. Plenty of pages on here to find next available cell in row/column.

Comment: I strongly suggest to read [about object Cells and object Range](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-cells/)